# How to show ActivityIndicator for scrollView in React native?

Tags: react-native, activity-indicator

I have used React native - **Activity Indicator** with scrollView for Form fields. while submitting form loading indicator is not displaying. Found solution for **FlatList** but how to display loader with **ScrollView**

`<ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" style={styles.loading} />` with

> *Styles.js*

```
loading: {
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 10000,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        // backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    }
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form to the server, using any API?

Answer (score 2):

Does your Activity Indicator need to be inside the scroll view? Why can't you render another View while the form is being submitted?
Like the GIF below:

[image]

I've build a full example to you [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@juniorklawa/thrilled-donut)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use ....

```
  <View style={LayoutStyle.indicatorWithLoader}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />
  </View>
```

and LayoutStyle.js like

```
 indicatorWithLoader: {
   flex: 1,
   position: 'absolute',
   right: 0,
   left: 0,
   zIndex: 9999999,
   //backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)', // for flip image or else remove this
   alignItems: 'center', // for flip image or else remove this
   justifyContent:'center', // for flip image or else remove this
 },
```

hope it's working I think

Comment: I required for `<ScrollView />`. In View/FlatList it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. create loading state for your loader.

   const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
2. create your custom loader:-

   ```
   <View style={styles.loader}>
     <View style={styles.backdrop} />
     <ActivityIndicator color={colors.primary} />
   </View>
   ```

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   loader: {
   width: "100%",
   height: "100%",
   position: "absolute",
   zIndex: 99999,
   elevation: 5,
   alignItems: "center",
   justifyContent: "center",
   },
   backdrop: {
   backgroundColor: "#000",
   opacity: 0.8,
   width: "100%",
   height: "100%",
   position: "absolute",
   }
   });
3. use the loading state to conditionally render the loader:-

   ```
    { isLoading ? <Loader/> : (
     <ScrollView>

     // rest of your code

     <Button onPress = {()=>{yourFn(); setLoading(true);}/>

    </ScrollView>)}
   ```